# H264 HW Decoding on Android Using FFmpeg-10

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264, stagefright

I've noticed that ffmpeg has already included (libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp) and claimed to support H264's hardware decoding through StageFright framework. I've build the shared library according to (tools/build_libstagefright). But when doing real H264 frame decoding, it seems to be failed at Stagefright_init().
Does anybody succeed to use this new feature? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How it failed any error message?

Comment: in libstagefright.cpp avctx->extradata_size==0 and it's failed to init correctly.